# Will deploying an AWS quick start in the same tenant conflict with an existing installation?

Tags: amazon-cloudformation

I do have only one AWS tenant. There is an application (Atlassian Jira + Confluence) which is running productively in this tenant.

Now I want to test a new version of this AWS QuickStart. If I will deploy this into the same tenant, do I run the risk of impacting the existing productive application?

Of course, I would be using some different public DNS names on the LB for the new setup. But I wonder if there are any names in the QuickStart's CF templates which may conflict.